# Grouping in list of symbols

Tags: symbols, glossaries, nomenclature

Could you tell me how to get the grouping? The center bold words, meaning, Number of Arrays, sets etc:

[image]

mwe:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[symbols,nogroupskip,sort=none]{glossaries-extra}

\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={position}]{x}{\ensuremath{x}}
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={velocity}]{v}{\ensuremath{v}}
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={acceleration}]{a}{\ensuremath{a}}
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={time}]{t}{\ensuremath{t}}
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={force}]{F}{\ensuremath{F}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\printunsrtglossary[type=symbols,style=long]

\chapter{Sample}
Reference symbols: $\gls{x}$, $\gls{v}$, $\gls{a}$, $\gls{t}$,
$\gls{F}$.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should get you started:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[record,style=alttreegroup,nomain,symbols]{glossaries-extra}

\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={position}, group={first}]{x}{\ensuremath{x}}
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={velocity}, group={first}]{v}{\ensuremath{v}}
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={acceleration}, group={second}]{a}{\ensuremath{a}}
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={time}, group={second}]{t}{\ensuremath{t}}
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={force}, group={second}]{F}{\ensuremath{F}}

\renewcommand\glstreegroupheaderfmt[1]{\begingroup\centering \textbf{#1}\par\endgroup}
\glsfindwidesttoplevelname
\glsxtrsetgrouptitle{first}{Numbers and Arrays}
\glsxtrsetgrouptitle{second}{Sets}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents


\printunsrtglossaries

\chapter{Sample}
Reference symbols: $\gls{x}$, $\gls{v}$, $\gls{a}$, $\gls{t}$,
$\gls{F}$.

\end{document}
```

Comment: It compiles with no errors but the group title does not appear. I have this `\usepackage[symbols,nogroupskip,sort=none]{glossaries-extra}`

Comment: @NaveganTeX: In my answer, I also changed the style and added `style=alttreegroup` to the options of the `glossaries-extra` package. If you use this style (or the exact same example code as in my answer), you should get the grouping.

Comment: My bad. I forgot to put `group={first}`...!

Comment: This is what I was looking for, but I'm wondering if it would be possible to get the symbols within a group automatically sorted in alphabetical order.