# Symbols clashing in List Of Symbols

Tags: symbols, glossaries, nomenclature

I don't know why this is happening:

[image]

This is my setup:

```
\usepackage[abbreviations,record,style=alttreegroup,nomain,symbols]{glossaries-extra}
\renewcommand\glstreegroupheaderfmt[1]{\begingroup\centering \textbf{#1}\par\endgroup}

\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={Calificación promedio de todos los usuarios y películas}]{r}{\ensuremath{\bar r}}
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={Sesgo del usuario $u$ en comparación con el promedio $\bar{r}$ }]{b_{u}}{\ensuremath{b_{u}}}
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={Sesgo de la película $i$ en comparación con el promedio $\bar{r}$}]{B_{i}}{\ensuremath{b_{i}}}
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={Calificación del usuario $u$ para la película $i$}]{r_{ui}}{\ensuremath{r_{ui}}}
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={Calificaci\'on predicha del usuario $u$ para la película $i$ }]{r{ui}}{\ensuremath{\hat{r}_{ui}}}
```

On the thesis.tex main file I've got like this:

```
\printunsrtglossary[type=symbols, title = Lista de S\'imbolos]
\printunsrtglossary[type=abbreviations,title = Lista de Abreviaciones]
```

Could you tell me what is going on with my example?

MWE from [Leandris](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/570804/185467)

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[record,style=alttreegroup,nomain,symbols]{glossaries-extra}

\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={position}, group={first}]{x}{\ensuremath{x}}
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={velocity}, group={first}]{v}{\ensuremath{v}}
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={acceleration}, group={second}]{a}{\ensuremath{a}}
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={time}, group={second}]{t}{\ensuremath{t}}
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={force}, group={second}]{F}{\ensuremath{F}}

\renewcommand\glstreegroupheaderfmt[1]{\begingroup\centering \textbf{#1}\par\endgroup}
\glsfindwidesttoplevelname
\glsxtrsetgrouptitle{first}{Numbers and Arrays}
\glsxtrsetgrouptitle{second}{Sets}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents


\printunsrtglossaries

\chapter{Sample}
Reference symbols: $\gls{x}$, $\gls{v}$, $\gls{a}$, $\gls{t}$,
$\gls{F}$.

\end{document}
```

**MAYBE `style=alttreegroup`** is causing the problem?

[image]

Comment: Did you also use `\glsfindwidesttoplevelname` in your actual document, just as I did in my example? This should solve your issue.

Comment: It says `unrecognized command`

Comment: From your comments under my previous answer, I assume, the code in the end did compile for you. Is that correct? There I already used `\glsfindwidesttoplevelname`as well. Could you please prepare a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that shows exactly what you currently do? If I try to make such an example with the information you provided so far, I end up with a compiling document and the following output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0oxz.png

Comment: Check mu updated post

Comment: The image you show does not show an error message from latex itself but a message from your IDE (presumably TeXStudio?) that for some reason does not know this particular command. What happens if you nevertheless compile your document? This message should not influence the output. See also: [TeXStudio doesn't recognize some commands](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/47493/134144) and [How does TXS know about valid commands?](https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/wiki/Frequently%20Asked%20Questions/#how-does-txs-know-about-valid-commands)

Comment: When I compile it, it does not throws any error, but the symbols clash with their description. On the other hand, If I remove `style=alttreegroup`, everything works fine but the group names dissapear.

Comment: Now it worked. I just added `\glsfindwidesttoplevelname` in the thesis.tex file instead of the packages file :)

Comment: Publish your MWE and I'l mark it as solved!

Comment: Good to hear that you were able to solve the issue. Since I just had another look at the screenshot you included, I wanted to let you know that you can chose whatever text you want to identify the individual groups. So you don't have to use `first`, `second`,... in `\glsxtrsetgrouptitle{first}`. Probably I should have chosen a better placeholder initially.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Too long for a comment: The following MWE works perfectly fine for me:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[abbreviations,record,style=alttreegroup,nomain,symbols]{glossaries-extra}

\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={Calificación promedio de todos los usuarios y películas}]{r}{\ensuremath{\bar r}}
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={Sesgo del usuario $u$ en comparación con el promedio $\bar{r}$ }]{b_{u}}{\ensuremath{b_{u}}}
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={Sesgo de la película $i$ en comparación con el promedio $\bar{r}$}]{B_{i}}{\ensuremath{b_{i}}}
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={Calificación del usuario $u$ para la película $i$}]{r_{ui}}{\ensuremath{r_{ui}}}
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={Calificaci\'on predicha del usuario $u$ para la película $i$ }]{r{ui}}{\ensuremath{\hat{r}_{ui}}}

\glsfindwidesttoplevelname
\renewcommand\glstreegroupheaderfmt[1]{\begingroup\centering \textbf{#1}\par\endgroup}

\begin{document}

\printunsrtglossary[type=symbols, title = Lista de S\'imbolos]
\printunsrtglossary[type=abbreviations,title = Lista de Abreviaciones]

\end{document}
```