# Duplicate glossary definitions in List of Symbols And Abbreviations

Tags: glossaries

How can I solve this? I have a duplicated definition on both lists:

[image]

[image]

This is what I've got in my packages.tex:

```
\usepackage[abbreviations,style=alttreegroup,record,nomain,symbols]{glossaries-extra}
\renewcommand\glstreegroupheaderfmt[1]{\begingroup\centering \textbf{#1}\par\endgroup}

\glsxtrsetgrouptitle{segundo}{Conjuntos}
\glsxtrsetgrouptitle{tercero}{Indexación}
\glsxtrsetgrouptitle{cuarto}{C\'alculo}
\glsxtrsetgrouptitle{quinto}{Probabilidad}
\glsxtrsetgrouptitle{sexto}{Funciones}
\glsxtrsetgrouptitle{sep}{Conjuntos de datos y distrubuciones}


\renewcommand{\glossarypreamble}{The following list describes various notations and symbols that will later be used within the body of the document, unless we redefine the notations based on context.}
```

And this is what I have in the main.tex file:

```
\glsfindwidesttoplevelname
\printunsrtglossary[type=symbols, title = List of Symbols   ]
\printunsrtglossary[type=abbreviations,title = List of Abbreviations]
```

MWE (credits to [Leandriss](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/570804/185467))

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[record,style=alttreegroup,nomain,symbols]{glossaries-extra}

\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={position}, group={first}]{x}{\ensuremath{x}}
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={velocity}, group={first}]{v}{\ensuremath{v}}
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={acceleration}, group={second}]{a}{\ensuremath{a}}
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={time}, group={second}]{t}{\ensuremath{t}}
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={force}, group={second}]{F}{\ensuremath{F}}

\renewcommand\glstreegroupheaderfmt[1]{\begingroup\centering \textbf{#1}\par\endgroup}
\glsfindwidesttoplevelname
\glsxtrsetgrouptitle{first}{Numbers and Arrays}
\glsxtrsetgrouptitle{second}{Sets}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents


\printunsrtglossaries

\chapter{Sample}
Reference symbols: $\gls{x}$, $\gls{v}$, $\gls{a}$, $\gls{t}$,
$\gls{F}$.

\end{document}
```

Comment: How exactly did you create the screenhot you show and what kind of output do you expect instead?

Comment: if doesn't make much sense to add a MWE which doesn't demonstrate your problem.

Comment: I have updated the OP!

Comment: Which of the two lists should contain the text you defined via `\glossarypreamble`?

Comment: Probably you could use something like the following in your preamble: `\setglossarypreamble[symbols]{The following list describes various notations and symbols that will later be used within the body of the document, unless we redefine the notations based on context.}`. This should only show the glossarypreamble text in the list of symbols, but not in the list of abbreviations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the `glossaries` user manual:

> [image: Blockquote]

Thus, if you only want your preamble text to be shown in the list of symbols only, you can use

```
\setglossarypreamble[symbols]{The following list describes various notations and symbols that will later be used within the body of the document, unless we redefine the notations based on context.}
```

instead of `\renewcommand{\glossarypreamble}{The...}`.

If you want a different, non-empty text for your list of abbreviations as well, add `\setglossarypreamble[abbreviations]{...}`.